# share image with host application from keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, share, android-softkeyboard

I want to share images from my keyboard application with the host app. For example if the user is using hangouts then I want to share an image with hangouts only. If the user is using FB Messenger then I want to share image with facebook messenger. Is this possible?

I tried to detect the last running application from the keyboard but it is not working since android 5.1.